Problem with illustrating pathways
This is slightly different from this and this question. We are focusing on an illustration of all pathways from a specific sample.
Suppose we have the following sample:
$$\small{\mathcal{S}=\left\{(-1.5,-1.7),(1.5,-1.2),(-1.5,-.7),(-1.5,-.2),(-1.5,.3),(-1.5,.8),(-1.5,1.3),(-1.5,1.8)\right\}}$$
Consider the following steps:
Procedure
If $d(Q,R)$ is the 2-d Euclidean-distance between sample points $Q,R\in\mathcal{S}$:

Take a point $x_0$ from $\mathcal{S}$
Take a point from $\mathcal{S}$ (excluding $x_0$) with smallest euclidean distance from point $x_0\in\mathcal{S}$. The point is denoted $x_1$, where we take $d(x_0,x_1)$. (If more than one point has the smallest Euclidean distance from $x_0$, split the pathway into mulitple pathways taking either point).
Take a point in $\mathcal{S}$ (excluding $x_0$ and $x_1$) with smallest euclidean distance from $x_1$. The point is denoted $x_2$, where we take $d(x_1,x_2)$. (If more than one point has smallest Euclidean distance from $x_1$, split the pathway into multiple pathways taking either point).
Take a point in $\mathcal{S}$ (excluding $x_0$, $x_1$, and $x_2$) with smallest euclidean distance from $x_2$. The point is denoted $x_3$, where we take $d(x_2,x_3)$. (If more than one point has the smallest Euclidean distance from $x_2$, split the pathway into multiple pathways taking either point).
Repeat the process excluding points $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,$ etc. until all points in the sample are "denoted". (This should occur $3$ more times.)
Take the largest subset of ${i}$-values, such that $d(x_i,x_{i-1})$  is not an outlier in the set of all distances of the "pathway": i.e.,
$$\left\{d(x_{t-1},x_{t}): t\in\mathbb{N}, 1\le t\le 7\right\}$$

Question: How do we illustrate this where the line segments in the pathway whose lengths are non-oultliers are black and the line segments in the pathway whose lengths are outliers are red?
Example
For instance, when $x_0=(1.5,-1.7)$, the pathway is:
$$\small{(-1.5,-1.7)\to(-1.5,-.7)\to(-1.5,-.2)\to(-1.5,.3)\to(-1.5,.8)\to(-1.5,1.3)\to(-1.5,1.8)\to(1.5,-1.2)}$$
Notice, $\left\{d(x_t,x_{t-1}): t\in\mathbb{N}, 1\le t\le 7\right\}$ is:
$$\small{\begin{alignat}{3}
& \{&& d(x_0,x_1),d(x_1,x_2),d(x_2,x_3),d(x_3,x_4),d(x_5,x_6),d(x_6,x_7) \}=\\[2pt]
& \{&& d((-1.5,-1.7),(-1.5,-.7)),d((-1.5,-.7),(-1.5,-.2)),d((-1.5,-.2),(-1.5,.3)),\\ & && d((-1.5,.3),(-1.5,.8)), d((-1.5,.8),(-1.5,1.3)),d((-1.5,1.3),(-1.5,1.8)),\\ & && d((-1.5,1.8),(1.5,-1.2))\}=\\[2pt]
& \{&& 1, .5, .5, .5, .5, .5, 3\sqrt{2}\}
\end{alignat}}$$
Also, the outlier of $\{ 1, .5, .5, .5, .5, .5, 3\sqrt{2}\}$ is $3\sqrt{2}$, when in decimal form. Hence, for $x_0=(-1.5,-1.7)$, since the length of line segments:
$$\overline{x_0 x_1}, \overline{x_1 x_2}, \overline{x_2 x_3}, \overline{x_3 x_4}, \overline{x_4 x_5}, \overline{x_5 x_6}$$
are non-outliers, the line segments should be black and since $\overline{x_6 x_7}$ is an outlier, the line segment should be red.
Attempt
I tried to illustrate the procedure (see beggening) for all $x_0\in\mathcal{S}$.
Below is $\mathcal{S}$:
S = {{-1.5, -1.7}, {1.5, -1.2}, {-1.5,-.7}, {-1.5,.2}, {-1.5, .3},
{-1.5, .8}, {-1.5, 1.3}, {-1.5, 1.8}};
S = Rationalize /@ S;

Below is steps 1-5 of the procedure (the distances aren't taken)
ClearAll[pathways, findnext];

pathways[start_List] := findnext[{start}];

findnext[path_List] := 
  Module[{candidates, now}, If[ContainsAll[path, S], Return[{path}]];
   now = Last[path];
   candidates = 
    MinimalBy[Complement[S, path], EuclideanDistance[now, #] &];
   Join @@ Table[findnext[Append[path, next]], {next, candidates}]];

Below are steps 1-6 of the procedure, execept we take the distances and repeat the steps for all $x_0\in\mathcal{S}$:
Table[
 init[q] = S[[q]]; (*x_0*)
 ans[q] = pathways[init[q]]; (*Takes all pathways for particular x_0*)
 Table[{
   OriginalDistances[q] = 
    N[Table[EuclideanDistance[ans[q][[t, s]], ans[q][[t, s + 1]]], {s,
        1, Length[ans[q][[t]]] - 1}]]; (*Takes d(x_t,x_{t+1}) for 1<=t<=7*)
   IndexofNonOutliers[q] = 
    Flatten[Position[OriginalDistances[q], 
      Alternatives @@ DeleteAnomalies[OriginalDistances[q]]]];
   (*Takes index of the start-points of all line segments in the "pathway" which are non-outliers*)
   D1[q] = 
    Table[ans[q][[t, s]], Evaluate[{s, IndexofNonOutliers[q]}]],
   (*Takes all start-points which are non-outliers*)
   arrow[coord_, e_] := 
    Piecewise[{{Style[Arrow[coord], Red, Thickness[.01], 
        Arrowheads[0.06]], 
       Boole[MemberQ[N /@ D1[q], First@coord]] == 0}, {Style[
        Arrow[coord], Black, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[0.06]], 
       Boole[MemberQ[N /@ D1[q], First@coord]] == 
        1}}]; (*Labels direction of pathway*)
   String1 = ToString /@ N[ans[q][[t]]];
   (*Labels arrows for "pathway" P*)
   Edge = 
    PathGraph[Range[Length[ans[q][[t]]]], 
     VertexCoordinates -> ans[q][[t]], EdgeShapeFunction -> arrow, 
     ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> .2, 
     VertexLabels -> 
      Table[i -> Subscript[x, i], {i, Length[ans[q][[t]]]}]]}, {t, 1, 
   Length[ans[q]]}], {q, 1, Length[S]}]

However, we get all line segments (in each pathway, for every $x_0\in\mathcal{S}$) are red rather than most of them being black.
Question Recap: Is there a more efficient code which correctly illustrates the procedure? If not, how do we fix my code so the procedure is correctly illustrated?

Since most of the points in $S$ are lying on a line, there is almost no merits in drawing straight arrows.....

@A.Kato I want to show the direction of the pathway. Depending on the $x_0,x_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot$ chosen, the pathway could move in different directions.

The code is a bit heavy and slow as you are not taking advantage of a few built-in functions or functional programming patterns.  I applied a functional programming approach which reduces the code and speeds it up.
s = Rationalize@{{-1.5, -1.7}, {1.5, -1.2}, {-1.5, -.7}, {-1.5, -.2},
                 {-1.5, .3}, {-1.5, .8}, {-1.5, 1.3}, {-1.5, 1.8}}

First lets start with the procedure steps 1 through 6.  Using Nearest and its DistanceFuction option with EuclideanDistance and a dash of recursion the pathways with equal step distance branching can be obtained by function pathway.
ClearAll[pathway]
pathway[path_, points_] :=
 Block[{$RecursionLimit = 2000} (* Make as large as your longest list *),
  Module[{next}
   , If[points == {}, Return[path]]
   ; next = Nearest[points, Last@path, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]
   ; Level[
      Map[pathway[Append[path, #], Delete[points, FirstPosition[points, #]]] &, next]
    , {-3}]
   ]
  ]

pathway takes the starting vertex and the remaining vertices as parameters and returns paths from the start including any equal step distance branches. s gives 14 paths.
paths = Flatten[pathway[{s[[#]]}, Delete[s, #]] & /@ Range@Length@s, 1]

Use Partition with an offset to get the edge pair steps for each path.
steps = Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ paths

Distances are calculated by Applying EuclideanDistance to the edge pair steps.
dists = Apply[EuclideanDistance, steps, {2}]

Next a limit for outliers of each path is defined as the median plus 1.5 times the interquartile range of the step distances of the path.
ClearAll[outlierLimit]
outlierLimit[distances_] :=
 Module[{q = Quartiles[distances], iqr}
  , iqr = First@Differences@q[[{1, 3}]] 
  ; q[[2]] + (3/2) iqr
  ]

outlierLimit is Mapped over each path's distances.
outLimits = outlierLimit /@ dists

Finally styles are defined for each step according to the path's outlier limit.
styles = 
 MapThread[
   GreaterThan[#1] /@ #2 &, {outLimits, dists}] /. {False -> Black, True -> Red}

Now all the parts needed for the PathGraph are available. I use the syntax that supplies the graph DirectedEdge edges and opted for the "Arrow" value for option EdgeShapeFunction to simplify things.
PathGraph[
   Range@Length@#1
   , Style @@@ Transpose[{DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Range@Length@#1, 2, 1], #2}]
   , VertexCoordinates -> #1
   , VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Subscript["x", i], {i, Length[#1]}]
   , EdgeShapeFunction -> "Arrow"
   ] & @@@ Transpose[{paths, styles}] // Multicolumn[#, 4] &


On my machine the speed is improved from around 7 seconds from OP's code to around 0.006 seconds from the functional approach code; 3 orders of magnitude faster. Also OP's code finds a total of 10 pathways with equal distance step branching while the above finds 14 pathways.
Hope this helps.

How do we accurately get rid of the outliers from dists? (I need this for future steps.)

@Arbuja To remove the outlier distances from dists you can use Select[#1, LessThan[#2]] & @@@ Thread[{dists, outLimits}]

This does not seem to be correct. For example the graph in first column third row. Distance between x1 and x2 is not shortest. A shorter one is between x1 and x8. OP's code is correct in finding only 10 pathways (not 14). Why accepting wrong answer?

@azerbajdzan The S in the OP code does not match the $\mathcal{S}$ in the LaTeX.  My code s matches the $\mathcal{S}$ in the LaTeX.  This is the difference that makes S 10 pathways and makes s 14 pathways; the incorrect entry of S.

@azerbajdzan You can further confirm as my path[[1]] has the same start point as the example in OP and path[[1]] matches the example's resulting pathway.

@Edmund So there are two different S. I did not look at LaTeX just at code. Then yes, one gives 10 paths another 14.

The one in the latex is the correct. Sorry.

Function paths[s] finds all possible paths for set of points s.
Function hg[path] highlights path path.
s1 = {{-1.5, -1.7}, {1.5, -1.2}, {-1.5, .7}, {-1.5, .2}, {-1.5, .3}, {-1.5, .8}, {-1.5, 1.3}, {-1.5, 1.8}} // Rationalize;
s2 = {{-1.5, -1.7}, {1.5, -1.2}, {-1.5, -.7}, {-1.5, -.2}, {-1.5, .3}, {-1.5, .8}, {-1.5, 1.3}, {-1.5, 1.8}} // Rationalize;

paths[s_] := 
  Flatten[Nest[
      Flatten[(e |-> ((d |-> Append[e, d]) /@ 
             Nearest[Complement[s, e], Last[e]])) /@ #, 1] &, {{#}}, 
      Length[s] - 1] & /@ s, 1];

paths[s1] // Length
paths[s2] // Length

hg[gr_] := 
 HighlightGraph[#, 
    EdgeList[#][[Flatten[Position[#, Max[#]]] &@(EuclideanDistance @@@
          Partition[gr, 2, 1])]]] &@
  PathGraph[gr, VertexCoordinates -> gr, DirectedEdges -> True, 
   VertexLabels -> "Index"]

hg /@ paths[s1] // Multicolumn[#, Appearance -> "Horizontal"] &
hg /@ paths[s2] // Multicolumn[#, Appearance -> "Horizontal"] &


10

14

One example out of 10 of s1.

One example out of 14 of s2.

